# Examples of melodic augmentation/diminuition

Tags: theory

I am looking for interesting musical examples of what might be called melodic augmentation/diminution. As contrasted with rhythmic augmentation/diminution, which can be thought of as a uniform scaling of the *note values* of a melody, a melodic augmentation/diminution would be a scaling of the *pitches*. This would result in a stretching or shrinking of the melodic contour.

Example: scaling the "Mary Had a Little Lamb" pitch sequence (4,2,0,2,4,4,4) by the factor 2 would yield (8,4,0,4,8,8,8).

I'd be happy with examples from any genre of music. Furthermore, this does not need to be considered as an operation only on melodies. Any example that illustrates a uniform scaling in the pitch dimension of a musical piece would be interesting to me.

Comment: I haven't seen this particular method applied. There is a rather common procedure in which a melody is reflected about a pitch axis. Thus a melody going up from C, C-D-E-F could be reflected about C and yield C-B-A-G (if in C major or something similar.) This is a "tonal " reflection; a "real" reflection would be" C-Bb-Ab- G. One can also reflect about another note. I don't have examples, but similar procedures should be covered under counterpoint, canon, and fugue procedures. Maybe this will get you started.